# Trying to gather my ingredients to a recipe in my MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to allow multiple ingredients to a recipe which I can figure out, but I want to collect all the ingredients to a recipe, if you are checking out an item that can be used in an ingredient. I hope that makes sense.

create_id in recipe_rel is to find what item which recipe should create.

```
recipes Table                               recipe_rel table

Recipe_id | item_needed_id | item_amount    recipe_id | create_id
-----------------------------------------   ---------------------
    1     |      5         |      3              1    |    12
-----------------------------------------   ---------------------
    1     |      2         |      2              2    |    18
-----------------------------------------   ---------------------
    2     |      8         |      1
-----------------------------------------
    2     |      3         |      1
```

So to clarify my problem, an item could be coal - so if i were to view coul, i'd like to see what i can create with coal.

I've tried to do something similar

```sql
SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE item_needed_id = 2
```

I also tried just getting the recipe id from the one i am picking at and use that but that seems to be alot of hardcoding, this is for a PHP page.

But I can't figure out on my own what I should write to get both ingredients in that, because right now I only get the row that has item needed id 2

My result should be getting all with recipe_id = 1 and also include if there should be a case where an item also uses (in this example) coal, should be listed on coal viewing page.

Like if coal can be used to create X and Y
You'd see full ingredients to X and Y on the Coal viewing page

I hope that make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  you can use this

```
Select Recipe_id, item_needed_id,item_amount From recipe 
Where Recipe_id in (SELECT Recipe_id FROM recipe WHERE item_needed_id = 2)
order by Recipe_id;
```

Result

```
Recipe_id   item_needed_id  item_amount
    1              5            3
    1              2            2
```

This shows all Recipes including item_need and amount for all recipes that have item_needed 2 in their ingredients list. I don't get why you posted  recipe_rel id.